# deployment failed using AzureDevops

Tags: azure, github, azure-cli

I'm followin this Azure Devops lab: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/github-azurepipelines/#task-4-embedding-automated

but when I'm deploying the app this error appears:

> There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
>      ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>      ##[error]Details:
>    ##[error]BadRequest: {
>     "error": {
>       "code": "InternalServerError",
>       "message": "There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again
>    later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: a016b467-fbd6-4851-a411-30f253ad4854"
>       }
>   }   undefined
>    ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

I don't know wich parameter is wrong, I try to make manual deploys and still fails.

Attached is the deployment detail I use to make the deploy.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "p_environment": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_separator": {
        "defaultValue": "-",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_site_prefix": {
        "defaultValue": "githubci",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_site_web_name": {
        "defaultValue": "web",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "p_comosdb_name": {
        "defaultValue": "db",
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "site_web_name": "[concat(parameters('p_site_prefix'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_site_web_name'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_environment'))]",
    "comosdb_default_name": "[concat(parameters('p_site_prefix'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_comosdb_name'), parameters('p_separator'), parameters('p_environment'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "kind": "MongoDB",
        "name": "[variables('comosdb_default_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "defaultExperience": "MongoDB"
        },
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('comosdb_default_name')]",
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "consistencyPolicy": {
                "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
                "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
                "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "app",
        "name": "[variables('site_web_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('site_web_name')]",
            "reserved": false,
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "COSMOS_DB_NAME",
                        "value":"[variables('comosdb_default_name')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "COSMOS_DB_AUTH_KEY",
                        "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', variables('comosdb_default_name')), '2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                        "value": "8.9.4"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/', variables('comosdb_default_name'))]"
        ]
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "web": {
            "type": "string",
             "value": "[variables('site_web_name')]"
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I could see what was missing.

Seems that there is a missing step on the lab. It should say that before you deploy the app you have to create an App Services Tier on Azure with the domain as it appears on the lab: githubci-web-...

Best regards.
Code Safe.